# Failed to Retrieve Data from mongoDB using findOne() method with 3 millions data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to search I didn't get the results for the newest records that I added by MongoDB compass community

```
router.get('/employee', (req,res) => {
  let searchQuery = {name: req.query.name};

  Employee.findOne(searchQuery)
    .then(employee => {
      res.render('search',{employee:employee});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'ERROR: '+err)
      res.redirect('/');
    })
});
```

Here is the schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
let employeeScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  postion: String,
  salary: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeScheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

`findOne()` will return the first document that satisfies the specified query. If you want to retrieve all documents that satisfy the specified query, use `find()`:

```
router.get('/employee', (req,res) => {
  Employee.find({name: req.query.name}).then((employee) => {
    res.render('search', {employee: employee});
  }).catch((err) => {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'ERROR: '+err);
    res.redirect('/');
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I had an issue while inserting data